# how to check getBytes(coloulm name) contain null value in java

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to check the below statement is null or not

byte[] imageBytes = rs.getBytes("doctimg");

my code is....

```
while(rs.next() ) {
    JsonObject row = new JsonObject();      

    /*Want  to Check this 
    byte[] imageBytes = rs.getBytes("doctimg");
    null or not*/
    byte[] imageBytes = rs.getBytes("doctimg");
    String imageBase64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes);

    row.add("doctId",new JsonPrimitive(""+rs.getString("doctId")));
    row.add("deptId",new JsonPrimitive(""+rs.getString("deptId")));


    row.addProperty("img", imageBase64);

    data.add(row);
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use `imageBytes == null`?

Comment: Which JDBC driver are you using. A correctly implemented JDBC driver should return `null` for `getBytes` if the column is null. The answer suggested by Mureinik to use `wasNull()` might work, but `wasNull()` is intended to be used when checking the null status after using one of the getters that returns a primitive value.

Comment: Yes!!! Its Working. Thanks for your suggestion. @Mark Rotteveel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`wasNull()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull--) method:

```
byte[] imageBytes = rs.getBytes("doctimg");
if (rs.wasNull()) {
    System.out.println("It was null!"); // or some more robust treatment
} else {
    // Wasn't null, let's use it
    String imageBase64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(imageBytes);
}
```